# Formatting time ago in words with phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to format time in my templates to read like "12 seconds ago" or "14 minutes ago". Ecto currently spits times out that look like `2016-06-28 21:35:21`.

Currently I'm just rendering out the time like this: `<p><%= post.inserted_at %></p>`.

I know ruby/rails has a function called `time_ago_in_words()` which does what I'm looking for. Maybe this can be done with the new Elixir 1.3 calendar types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Timex` hex package. Specifically [`from_now`](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#from_now/1) function. You need to make sure that you have a date of type DateTime. Then simply use

```
Timex.from_now(my_date)
#"2 hours ago"
```

To convert `Ecto.DateTime` to `Timex.DateTime` I used this

```
my_ecto_dateTime
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-05-16T16:26:55Z>
{:ok, date} =  Ecto.DateTime.dump(my_ecto_dateTime)
my_date = Timex.DateTime.from date
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a port from Rails](https://gist.github.com/tlemens/88e9b08f62150ba6082f478a4a03ac52)

```
time_ago_in_words(~N[2015-03-05 21:45:00])
"about 6 years"

distance_of_time_in_words(~N[2004-06-06 21:45:00], ~N[2004-06-06 21:45:00], include_seconds: true)
"less than 5 seconds"

distance_of_time_in_words(~N[2004-06-06 21:45:00], ~N[2004-06-06 21:45:00])                       
"less than a minute"
```